# Reading in shorts in a RandomAccessFile .csv

Tags: java, csv, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to read in a .csv file with 3 shorts in the beginning of the file. I need to read them in and I'm setting to a variable but it seems to not be pulling in the right data.

```
private short M = 0;
private short rootPtr = 0;
private short N = 0;
RandomAccessFile file;
private short[] TP; // array of TPs for one node
private String[] KV; // array of KVs for one node
private short[] DRP; // array of DRPs for one node
private int nodesRead; // iterator for nodes read
private int sizeOfDataRec; // stores size of data record: (M - 1) * (7) + 2

    // sets values from header record
    file.seek(0);
    M = file.readShort();
    rootPtr = file.readShort();
    N = file.readShort();
    sizeOfDataRec = (M - 1) * (7) + 2; // sets size of data record
    TP = new short[M];
    KV = new String[M - 1];
    DRP = new short[M - 1];
```

The first 3 shorts of the file should be 05,11,22 but I get 12344 when I print out M at the end of this bit

Comment: I suggest using a library for reading CSV file, if you have no constraints. (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java Docs of [RandomAccessFile#readShort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readShort())

> Reads a **signed 16-bit number** from this file. The method reads two
>   bytes from this file, starting at the current file pointer. If the two
>   bytes read, in order, are b1 and b2, where each of the two values is
>   between 0 and 255, inclusive, then the result is equal to:
>
> **(short)((b1 << 8) | b2)**
>
> This method blocks until the two bytes are read, the end of the stream
>   is detected, or an exception is thrown

Now lets see what is happening in your case, suppose first short value you are reading is 05

when **readShort** reads two bytes it will read 0 as 48 and 5 as 53 (remember ASCII codes) and then it applies above mentioned formula to it which gives

```
(48 << 8) | 53 = 12288 + 53 = 12341
```

So you are seeing these values in your short variables.

**You shall use Scanner#nextShort as suggested by EJP**

Comment: Scanner isn't compatible with a RandomAccessFile, right?

Comment: No it is not. you have to read it sequentially using a Scanner object

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is text. It doesn't contain shorts, and you can't expect to use `RandomAccessFile.readShort()` on it. More probably you should be using `Scanner.nextShort()` etc.